# How create a comma-separated string from items in a list

Tags: dart

If I print values in a list, it will be like below:

```
main(List<String> arguments) {
  List cities = ['NY', 'LA', 'Tokyo'];
  String s = '';
  for(var city in cities)
    s += '$city, ';
  print(s);//NY, LA, Tokyo, 
}
```

But I want to separate each element in a list by comma(**without for the last element**).

In Java we can do it like below:

```
List<String> cities = Arrays.asList("NY", "LA", "Tokyo");
System.out.println(cities.stream().collect(joining(", ")));//NY, LA, Tokyo
```

In Dart I **did** it like below:

```
main(List<String> arguments) {
  List cities = ['NY', 'LA', 'Tokyo'];
  print(formatString(cities));//NY, LA, Tokyo
}

String formatString(List x) {
  String formatted ='';
   for(var i in x) {
     formatted += '$i, ';
   }
  return formatted.replaceRange(formatted.length -2, formatted.length, '');
}
```

**Is there any simpler method in Dart?**

Answer (score 115, accepted):

This is how I do it using [`join()`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Iterable/join.html) in [`List`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/List-class.html):

```
main(List<String> arguments) {
  List cities = ['NY', 'LA', 'Tokyo'];

  String s = cities.join(', ');
  print(s);
}
```

Comment: You can ignore `.toString()` as join method returns type `String`.
[Read more on join method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Iterable/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Here the simple Solution using *extension***

> Use this extension code,  paste it globally

```
extension ListExtentions<T> on List<T> {
String listToString() => join(',');
}
```

> We can use this extension simply anywhere

```
yourStringList.listToString();
print(yourStringList.listToString());
```

> Detailed example given below

```
List citiesList = ['NY', 'LA', 'Tokyo'];
String citiesString = citiesList.listToString(); // citiesString will be NY, LA, Tokyo
print(citiesString);
output: NY, LA, Tokyo

//Simply use
print(citiesList.listToString());
```