# Convert array into comma separated value of String

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array and I want to convert it into String but separated each element by '","

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How create a comma-separated string from items in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407120/how-create-a-comma-separated-string-from-items-in-a-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<String> list = ["India","China","USA"]; 
var string = list.join(',');
print(string); //output = "India,China,USA"
```